# Hyper-V snapshots – unable to start VM

Tags: hyper-v

I restarted my Host server after shutting down three guest VMs. After I restarted the machine I tried to start the VMs and got an error stating the the VM failed to start.

SERVERNAME failed to start.

Attachment 'avhd file path' is read only. Please provide read/write access to the attachment. Error: 'General access denied error'

SERVENAME failed to start. (virtual machine ID 17292200-wd22-dd22-d23-dddddd2222)

The issue seems to be with the disk space. The VHD file for this VM is 128 GB and there are two AVHD files of 58 and 75 GB. Whereas the total disk space on this drive (E) is 280 GB - the free space is only around 23 GB. I understand that the error is caused by the unavailability of the required disk space.

Unfortunately, I cannot increase the disk space on this drive. However I have another drive (D) that has 400 GB of free space. I exported this VM to D drive and then tried to add the copied AVHD files but it gives me a similar error.

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the file permissions are correct?

Comment: How did you export the files?  Via the UI? Or did you just copy them?

Comment: Chris - The file permissions are correct. I have used this method to assign permissions to the avhd files. 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2249906

Steven - I exported the files through the Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: And the snapshots did not export with the VM image?  They should have exported to a Snapshots folder in the export process.

Comment: The snapshots did export and an AVHD file of the same size was created on the other drive. However the snapshots folder is empty, the AVHD file is in the same folder as the VHD file.

Comment: I have tried creating a new VM and then tried to merge the existing AVHD and VHD files according to this article:

http://www.networkfoo.org/server-infrastructure/recovering-your-virtual-machine-how-manually-merge-hyper-v-snapshots-back-one-

But I still get the same error:

'UATNEW': Attachment 'C:\Test UAT VM\UAT\UAT\Virtual Hard Disks\UAT_ED224380-XXX-4FD8-YYYY-D751A270835C.vhd' is read only. Please provide read/write access to add the attachment. Error: 'General access denied error' (7864368). (Virtual machine ID D31639AE-ZZZZ-CCCC-ACB6-564959991701)

Comment: did you try to import the exported machine as it stood?  Or did you go right into the steps from that article?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scenario and the discussion in the comments, I would attempt to import the exported VM as Hyper-V exported it.  You may need to adjust the location of files in the .exp file.

You will want to delete the previous machine's configuration from Hyper-V before importing the VM, if you want to keep the same VM ID.  If you don't care, you can re-import the VM with a new ID.